# Luis and QnA in same app

Tags: artificial-intelligence, azure-language-understanding

Is it possible to integrate QnA in my chatbot if it's created using luis? I want to use the intent "none" from luis to trigger QnA when luis don't have answer.
How i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Qna + LUIS Node.js](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/tree/master/Node/samples/QnAWithLUIS) sample.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

In Luis dialog add this

```
[LuisModel("modelID", "SubscriptionKey")]
[Serializable]
public class RootDialog : LuisDialog<object>
{
    [LuisIntent("None")]
    public async Task NoneRes(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
            var qnadialog = new QnADialog();
            await context.Forward(new QnADialog(), AfterQnADialog, context.Activity, CancellationToken.None);
    }
    private async Task AfterQnADialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var answerFound = await result;
        // handle after qna response
    }
}
```

And in QnADialog add this

```
[Serializable]
[QnAMaker(authKey: "AuthKey", knowledgebaseId: "KnowledgebaseId", defaultMessage: "please rephrase, I could not understand.", scoreThreshold: 0.5, top: 1, endpointHostName: "https://yourAccount.azurewebsites.net/qnamaker")]
public class QnADialog : QnAMakerDialog
{}
```

So whenever your LUIS will return None intent it will call the QnADialog where in the attribute itself you will give the AuthKey, Knowledgebase ID, default response, host address etc. and it will work.

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

You may try the [Dispatch tool for multiple LUIS and QnA models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-dispatch?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs):

> If a bot uses multiple LUIS models and QnA Maker knowledge bases (KBs), you can use Disptach tool to determince which LUIS model or QnA Maker KB best maches the user input. The dispatch tool does this by creating a single LUIS app to route user input to the corrrect model.

The tool is available for Bot Builder SDK v4.